# How do I write the number of characters in a div?

Tags: document.write, string-length

I'm trying to display the character count of various divs I have on a page.

I have this:

```
<div class="myText">Here is some text.</div>
<div class="myText">Here is some more text.</div>
```

I'd like to display the character count after each one. So the page would look like this:

**Here is some text. 18**

**Here is some more text. 23**

I know I can use jQuery:

```
$('.myText').text().length
```

combined with

```
document.write
```

but I have no idea how (I'm just starting to learn javascript). Also, the divs are generated by our CMS so there are going to be a lot of them and I'd like to get character counts for them all so maybe they each need different class names?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.myText').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.append($this.html().length);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tadeu, but what part actually displays the number on screen? I set up a fiddle but can't get it to display the count. http://jsfiddle.net/Ht694/

Comment: You changed the className for the div, it was `myText` and you changed it to `mytext` you also forgot including the jQuery library. http://jsfiddle.net/bcphM/1/